Reduction formula: Show that if $I_n=\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$, then $I_n = \frac{n-1}{n+2} I_{n-2}, \>n≥2$
I couldn't figure out the reduction formula $I_n = \frac{n-1}{n+2} I_{n-2}$ for the integral $I_n=\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$ for each non-negative integer $n\geq 2$.
I couldn't figure this one out without ending up with powers of 3/2 which didn't fit with the reduction formula.

Maybe you could use a manipulation such as: $\int_0^1 x^n (1-x^2)^{3/2} dx = \int_0^1 x^n (1-x^2) \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = I_n - I_{n+2}$?

Hint: Substitute $x = \sin \theta$.

Duplicate of given $I_{n}=\int^1_{0}x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, then finding value of $ \frac{I_{n}}{I_{n-2}}$, Recurrence for integral $I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\sqrt{1-x^2}: dx$, and $\frac{\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}$; near-duplicate of Definite Integration with limits. Found via approach0.xyz

Let's cheat our way through
$\begin{aligned}
I_n=\displaystyle\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\overset{(\ast)^1}{=}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n u\cos^2 u\,\mathrm du&\overset{(\ast)^2}{=}\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak B\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
&\overset{(\ast)^3}{=}\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+4}{2})}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2}+1)\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2}+1)}\\
&\overset{(\ast)^4}{=}\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\frac{n-1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{\frac{n+2}{2}\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n+2}\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n+2}\mathfrak B\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n+2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2} u\cos^2 u\,\mathrm du\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n+2}\int_0^{1}x^{n-2} \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{n-1}{n+2}I_{n-2}
\end{aligned}$
Where $\mathfrak B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function, $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is Euler's gamma function and
$$\begin{aligned}
&(\ast)^1:x=\sin u;\ \mathrm dx=\cos u\,\mathrm du\\
&(\ast)^2:\mathfrak B(n,m)\equiv 2\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n-1}(\cos x)^{2m-1}\,\mathrm dx\\
&(\ast)^3:\mathfrak B(n,m)\equiv\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(n+m)}\\
&(\ast)^4:\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)
\end{aligned}$$

You can also get to the beta function representation of $I_n$ a bit more directly using the substitution $x := \sqrt{t}$.

Yes, I just noticed that I could've used the other integral definition of the beta function, the one with the root.

Extablish
\begin{align}
&\left[x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{3/2}\right]’
=\left[(n-1)x^{n-2}- (n+2)x^n\right] \sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{align}
and integrate both sides of the equation to obtain $I_n = \frac{n-1}{n+2} I_{n-2}$.

$$I_n:= \int_0^1x^n \sqrt{1-x^2}dx =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^n(x) \cos^2(x)dx$$
$$= \frac{\sin^{n+1}( x) \cos(x)}{n+1} \bigg|_0^\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n+2}(x) dx =\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}(x) (1-\cos^2(x)) dx$$ $$= \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}(x) dx - \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}(x) \cos^2(x) dx$$
$\\[5pt]$
$$I_n =\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}(x) dx -\frac{I_n}{n+1}  $$
$\\[5pt]$
$$I_n \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1} \right)= \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}(x) dx   = \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n-1}(x) \sin(x) dx $$
$$= - \frac{cos(x) \sin^{n-1}(x)}{n+1} \bigg|_0^\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{n-1}{n+1} \int _{0}^ \frac{\pi}{2} \sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^2(x) =\frac{n-1}{n+1} I_{n-2} $$
$\\[5pt]$
$$I_n \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1} \right)=\frac{n-1}{n+1} I_{n-2} $$
$$I_n = \frac{n-1}{n+2} I_{n-2}$$

For any $n\ge 2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n&=\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2} d x \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\left(1-x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x \\
&=-\int_0^1\left(x^{n-1}-x^{n+1}\right) d\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \\
&= {(n-1) \int_0^1 x^{n-2} \sqrt{1-x^2} d x-(n+1) \int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2} dx} \quad \textrm{ (via IBP)} \\
&= {(n-1) I_{n-2}-(n+1) I_n} \\
\therefore I_n&=\frac{n-1}{n+2} I_{n-2} 
\end{aligned}
$$
